# SQL Server 2008 Deploy app

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I created the database on SQL Server 2008 and connect to it

```
  {.ConnectionString = "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test;User=sa;Pwd=test;"}
```

Now i want to deploy that application so my friend can test it. I have no idea how to make it possible or is it possible at all ( is the database on my localhost ) ?

I would really could use some help because first time working with it.

Comment: `Is the database on my localhost?` Yes, according to your connection string. If you want your friend to test the app you'll either need to send them a copy of the database or set up a database server somewhere online that you can both access.

Comment: @TZHX if i send him copy of the database ? He also must have the sql server installed so he can test it ?

Comment: Yes, if you want your app to run and use this database file, then SQL Server **Express** must be installed on that system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create local mdf database file in your project and slightly change your connection string to attach it to sqlexpress instance.

```
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                          AttachDbFilename=test.mdf;
                          Integrated Security=True;
                          User Instance=True";
```

It worth to mension that your friend has to have sql server express installed.

Comment: This *still* requires that SQL Server **Express** be installed locally on that system where this app should run ...

Comment: I just went with local mdf database

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to make a backup of your DB as follows.`BACKUP DATABASE [Accounting] TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Test.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'Accounting-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10`
then they can restore it as follows on there mssqlserver:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DBRooiabooking] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Test.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
```

and they can use it .
with the same connectionstring .
Best Regards